# adding substring to results.input1 in cordova prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a substring to the input text that removes first character of the input text. Here is my code below. I tried a lot but didn't get the desired output.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.notification);
    }
    function onPrompt(results){ 
    alert("You entered " + results.input1, 'Results', 'OK');
    };
    function showPrompt(){
    navigator.notification.prompt(
        'Please enter your name',  // message
        onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
        'Registration',            // title
        ['Play','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
        'Type your name'                 // defaultText
    );
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><a href="" onclick="showPrompt(); return false;">Show Prompt</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I'm not seeing anything to attempt removing the first character or even where it's supposed to happen...

Comment: I mean if an user enters abcd in the prompt field, the output should be bcd. I want the first character to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use substr... like:

```
var cutInput = input.substr(1)
```

This gives you the input string starting at character 1 (zero indexed, so the first character is at position 0), through the end of the string.

Without knowing where you want it in your code, here's an example just for s&g's:

```
function onPrompt(results){ 
    var cutInput = results.input1.substr(1); //assuming that's the string in question
    alert("You entered " + cutInput, 'Results', 'OK');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the substring functionality of Javascript.

```
var subStr = wholeStr.substring(1);
```

Here is a JSFiddle of it doing what you want: [substring in action](http://jsfiddle.net/8mfpfkg0/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for then is JavaScript's in-built [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method for Strings.

Example (from the link)

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

Comment: If you really tried yourself, I am sure you could apply it your self.. Hmm.. Could it be like: var what_you_want = results.input1.substr(1);

Comment: Your example would yield "ell" from "Hello world!"

Comment: @Ted: Yes?? As already mentioned in my post, it is copy-paste from the link. Idea of SO isn't to provide ready code for people that don't want to use any effort.

Comment: Well maybe since it's almost Christmas that I'm feeling more giving than to just link to an external sample. Also, edit your link text to read 'substring' which you've linked to. `substr` is a different function that would yield [different results](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) with your given example/arguments.

Comment: Well spotted, my bad on that, thanks! I suppose it is okay then with the Christmas coming, merry Christmas!